# Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017] at null using MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm a attempting to run a node application and keep receiving this error. Not sure where to start:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/dte/limetime-dev/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:557:74)
    at emit (events.js:118:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/dte/limetime-dev/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/dte/limetime-dev/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at net.js:451:14
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

Comment: Start here: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Voting to close this question because it lacks a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your mongodb is not running or is running on different port.
Node app doesn't manage mongoDB for you.
So before running your app make sure mongodb is running on port 27017.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that MongoDB is not running on your current host.  Make sure MongoDB is running.  Check out http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/ for instructions on installing MongoDB.